# How we store error/success messages to the next page

Tags: errors

I am working on site. I uses some custom `error/success` messages for front end form but currently it display messages to on same page, But as soon as I refresh the page or redirect the user to next page messages not save. To save the `success messages` I use the `code`

```
$success = __('You have successfully Login.', 'frontendprofile');
```

And for the error messages I use the  default varible that is `$error`. How can save them the for next page or for when if I refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the messages in a `$_SESSION` variable. This way, the values will be preserved untill you decide to remove them again.

```
function save_message( $type, $message = '' ) {
    $_SESSION['messages'][$type] = $message;
}

function get_messages() {
    $return = '';

    if ( isset( $_SESSION['messages'] ) && is_array( $_SESSION['messages'] ) ) {
        foreach( $_SESSION['messages'] as $type => $message ) {
            $return .= sprintf( '<p class="%1$s">%2$s</p>', $type, $message );
        }
    }

    if ( strlen( $return ) > 0 )
        return $return;

    return false;
}

function clean_messages( $type = false ) {
    if ( ! $type )
        $_SESSION['messages'] = array();

    else
        unset( $_SESSION['messages'][$type];
}
```

Something like this.
You can use it like follows:

```
save_message( 'success', __( 'You have successfully Login.', 'frontendprofile' ) );

if ( $messages = get_messages() ) {
    echo $messages;

    clean_message('success');
}
```